# Error 91 when i try change from a String to a Variable (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

So, im having some problems trying to find and copy content from one workbook from another, here is my code:

```
Sub beta()


Dim actual As Workbook: Set actual = ActiveWorkbook
Dim brf As Workbook: Set brf = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="brf.csv", Local:=True)
brf.Sheets("brf").Range("A1:E1").Delete
brf.Sheets("brf").Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim numerofilas As Integer
Dim etiqueta As String
Dim caudal As Double
actual.Activate

numerofilas = actual.Sheets(1).Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

actual.Sheets(1).Range("H1").Select
For x = 1 To numerofilas
    etiqueta = ActiveCell.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 
    brf.Sheets("brf").Range("D:D").Find(etiqueta).Offset(0, 1).Value

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Inside For() Loop, when I assign like "123" to etiqueta it works perfect, but when I try to assign the ActiveCell.Value I´m getting "Error (91)" in execution.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also add the text that accompanies the error number? Also, do you know which line of code the error happens on?

Comment: You're not trapping for the possibility of it not finding the text you're looking for. You can't set the `.Value` of a cell to `Nothing`. You need to trap the `Nothing` and if necessary replace it with `""`,`No match` or similar.

Comment: Which line specifically is throwing the error, my guess is it is the `Find` line.  When the `Find` does not "find" the value then it returns nothing and nothing has no value, hence the error.

Comment: @Mistella error 91 is "Object or With block variable not set". VBA's `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Aww what a noob mistake, thank you everyone and sorry i´m not use to code in vba.